# url intent starts app in firefox, but not in chrome and android browser

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

when i enter the following url in firefox it opens my app, but not in chrome and the android browser

```
myschema://ROOT/kategorie
```

my intent filter is defined in my launch activity like this

```
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <data android:scheme="myschema"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

do i have to write my url different in this browsers ?

Comment: yes. see https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/intents

Comment: yes i also discovered this link, but is it the same for the standard android browser ?

Comment: I think the "myschema://..." style has been discontinued. I am trying to figure out how to use the "intent://..." style instead, but without luck so far since I do not understand the format: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418691/how-do-i-write-an-android-intent-for-chrome-to-open-the-gmail-app-and-search