# How do I write an Android intent for Chrome to open the GMail app and search?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, gmail

It is possible to start an app and request some action from Chrome web-browser in Android:

Android Intents with Chrome - Google Chrome Mobile — **Google Developers** 
https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

There is an example:

```
<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>
```

I have tried to write something similar to start the GMail app. I have tried various versions, but all that happens is that the Google Play APP is opened showing GMail. Here is one attempt I have made:

```
<a href="intent://dummy/#Intent;package=com.google.android.gm;action=android.intention.action.VIEW;category=;component=;scheme=;end">Gmail, android.intention.action.VIEW</a>
```

I would like to open the GMail app and do a search, but I can't even open it. ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the link fix, @arka.b.

Comment: Has anyone seen any news about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it can't be done.  Gmail would have to be set to be "Browseable" which means it is able to be opened from the web and I don't see it in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks Kinlan. Yes, it looks like it cannot be done yet. Searching for more info my impression is that the Google might be waiting for emerging standards for "intent://". Or, they might have decided against it (which would be very unfortunate, but maybe welcome by Firefox... ;-) ).