# Make Link For Open Gmail Application and Search Email

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, gmail

I am looking for create link which can work for open android gmail application and search email which sent by us. I have link for desktop browser like below

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/sample@gmail.com/?tab=rm&ogbl#search/user@example.com
```

Its working fine for desktop but for android its not working.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418691/how-do-i-write-an-android-intent-for-chrome-to-open-the-gmail-app-and-search) and similar questions and answers

which is opening playstore and searching gmail application in it. I want similar link to generate which can open gmail application and search the email. I think its possible but I do not know how.

Let me know if anyone here can help me for solve the puzzle. Thanks!

Comment: According to this article it might not be possible https://growth.design/sniper-link

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?